# SQL Fiddle MySQL 5.6 vs MS SQL Server 2017 - simple create and insert

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-insert, create-table, sqlfiddle

I am running the following query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

With MySQL 5.6 the following works fine:

```
create table test (col_1 varchar(10), col_2 int);

insert into test (col_1, col_2)
values ("A", 3),
      ("B", 7),
      ("A", 1),
      ("B", 2);
```

But with MS SQL Server 2017 for the same query. I am getting back error:

```
Invalid column name 'A'.
```

Should the syntax be the same for both SQLs?

Here is a snapshot of error:[image]

Comment: It’s incorrect to think that sql implementation is the same across all vendors

Comment: try use single quote around  A , B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use single quote  (double quote in SQLserver are for columns name)

```
  insert into test (col_1, col_2)
  values ('A', 3),
        ('B', 7),
        ('A', 1),
        ('B', 2);
```